# Create custom tab in WordPress 5 media upload

Tags: uploads, media-library, block-editor

Can someone help me create custom tab in WordPress media library. With WordPress version 4 i used to `media_upload_tabs` function to build that nice work. But now, in WordPress version 5 the function is not working.

[image: This image is WordPress media library version 5]

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could get this to work in WP 5 was to install the [Classic Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/classic-editor/).

Then I could use [media_view_settings](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/media_view_settings/) to add the tab.

```
add_filter('media_view_settings', 'addMediaTab');

function addMediaTab($settings) {
    $settings['tabs'] = array('mymediatab' => 'My Media Tab');
    return $settings;
}
```

BUT it appears the new UI doesn't include those sections in Gutenberg, you will end up with something like this if you use the Classic Editor.

[image: WP 5 New Media Tab]

**You can also do this with JS.**

```
var Library = wp.media.controller.Library;
var oldMediaFrame = wp.media.view.MediaFrame.Post;

wp.media.view.MediaFrame.Post = oldMediaFrame.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        oldMediaFrame.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
        var options = this.options;
        this.states.add([
            new Library({
                id: 'inserts',
                title: 'My New Tab',
                priority: 20,
                toolbar: 'main-insert',
                filterable: 'all',
                library: wp.media.query(options.library),
                multiple: false,
                editable: false,
                library: wp.media.query(_.defaults({
                    newtab: 'newtab',
                }, options.library)),
                displaySettings: true,
                displayUserSettings: true
            }),
        ]);
    },
});
```

**More Info**

[Ticket with more info about Media_upload_tabs & WP5](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/45802#comment:5)

[JS Demo Example](https://www.ibenic.com/extending-wordpress-media-uploader-custom-tab/)

Comment: At first i thought so but i seen a plugin working that is stencil plugin, this is link `https://wordpress.org/plugins/stencil/. i'm learning it but it's quit hard to understand.

Comment: @Mr.hiepdz stencil looks like an amazing plugin too. Hidden gem!